# How to animate Divi dividers?

Tags: css, divi

I would like to animate a Divi Divider. (Divi is a Builder and theme for WordPress)

So in the default CSS you find this class:

```
.et_pb_bottom_inside_divider{ 
background-size:100% 110px;
bottom:0;height:110px;
}
```

110px is the value, that need to be faded. When I set it to 200 it has the hight, so I am sure it is the correct class.

So what I did is I wrote some CSS and added it to the CSS of the WordPress. First you the class with adding the new animation name and details. 2nd the animation itself.

Problem: Nothing happens. When I the new height to the first class, it gets the height. So also working in general.

```
.et_pb_bottom_inside_divider {
    animation-name: xcxcxcxc;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;   
}
@keyframes xcxcxcxc {
    0% {background-size:100% 110px!important; height:110px!important;}
    100% {background-size:100% 210px!important; height:210px!important;}
}
```

If you have an idea let me know.
Regards C

PS: I know there are some tuts how to animate the Divi divider over the backend, but only over scroll efffect. I would need to have it animated when loaded etc.

Here a picture for better understanding. So now with 110px the optical divider is till the red arrow. With the animation I would like it to go up to something like the yellow arrow. (210px)
[image]

Comment: What exacly is the problem that happens now? your explaination is not very clear (the best option would be to create a snippet that recreates the problem here so we can see it in action)

Comment: Hi Ramon, I added a pic. Is it now better to understand?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.
Everything was right except the important. When removed, it worked :)